# Google Maps - create polygon with group of lon/lat points

Tags: maps, latitude-longitude, shapes

I have groups of 10 to 700 longitude and latitude points around a city or region.
I would like to create a polygon or "blob" to cover area defined by these points.

I Could pre-process points on our server to save time.

has anyone done anything like this or seen any useful tools?

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the polygon you talk about you need the compute the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of your points. There are plenty of algorithms available. [Here](http://westhoffswelt.de/blog/0040_quickhull_introduction_and_php_implementation.html) you can find one in PHP.